# "The document 1" or "Document 1"?

Tags: articles

When analyzing a document, I'd like to know if we had to use a definite article or not: "**The document 1**" or "**Document 1**"? And what is the reasoning behind its use or its non-use?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please give a sample sentence and some context.

Comment: @Greybeard for instance, "The document 1 highlights the fact that the United States is an hegemonic country" or "Document 1 highlights the fact that the United States is an hegemonic country"?

Comment: Thanks. "Document 1" is, in fact, a name that has been given to that document. Like all names it should be capitalised and **does not** usually accept the definite article. (As a test, you can substitute "John" for "Document 1".)

Comment: @Greybeard Oh, okay! This is very clear. Thank you very much for your quick reply.

Comment: "The document 1" is incorrect. You can either say "Document 1" when referring to a specific document named "Document 1" or "The first document" when referring to the first (possibly unnamed) document in a list.